# MySQL Group and count rows with data

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds different kinds of data. what I would like to achieve is that I want to run a query through the database looking for rows that are equal in number and have the same content like say column has id 1 with 3 rows, and column has id 5 with 3 rows and all these values are same. I want to 
    consider that as a group then count how many they are. Rows with different ids but same values. Then have a table that shows count that x matches were found and contains  this+this+this values. This is in MySQL

```
id  |  drug
--------------
1   | LAMIVUDINE
----------------
1   | ZIDOVUDINE
----------------
1   | 3TC
----------------
3   | TTC
-------------
4   | KKY
------------
4   | JJ2
-------------
4   | FFF
---------------
5   | LAMIVUDINE
----------------
5   | ZIDOVUDINE 
-----------------
5   | 3TC
------------------
8   | KKY
----------------
8   | JJ2
--------------
8   | FFF
---------------
```

count(id) AS number

drug As name

```
number |  name
-------------------------------------
2      | LAMIVUDINE + ZIDOVUDINE + 3TC
---------------------------------------
2      | KKY + JJ2 + FFF
--------------------------------------`
1      | TTC
---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` with a `+` separator  for concatenate rows with same id and then do another group by on concatenated values to get the desired output

```
select count(*) number, names
from (
    select count(*) total, group_concat(drug order by drug separator '+') names
    from table1
    group by id
) t 
group by names
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/ZHMYOG86953)

Order by clause is important inside group by so that concatenated string values should be in same order